# CSS "grid" layout with modern CSS (no JS)

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

**WANTED**

I'd like to have a grid layout. 
A bit like Pinterest, except the items have fixed height (so it should be a lot easier).

It should be responsive. The number of colums should be set according to the viewport size.

The DOM should be a simple list of childs inside a container. I don't want a wrapper element for each row. What I want is this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
    <div class="item">f</div>
    <div class="item">g</div>
    <div class="item">h</div>
    <div class="item">i</div>
</div>
```

The ordering of items matter, so the "b" item of the DOM should be on the right of the "a" item (and not under).

[image: layout]

**MY ATTEMPT**

I have done [this layout](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyLqVB?editors=111) using flexbox but it feels quite hacky as I have to compute some margins with maths. Also I don't understand how to control the vertical space between my flexbox rows, as it seems to grow with the container height.

Here is my LESS mixin of the Codepen above:

```
.flexboxGridMixin(@columnNumber,@spacingPercent) {
  @contentPercent: 100% - @spacingPercent;
  @sideMargin: @spacingPercent/(@columnNumber*2);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: (100% - @spacingPercent)/@columnNumber;
    margin-left: @sideMargin;
    margin-right: @sideMargin;
  }
}
```

It seems doing math like that somehow defeat the initial purpose of flexbox no?

**EXPECTED ANSWER**

So, can someone explain me how to fix my flexbox layout? Or tell me what is the best, most elegant and modern way to solve this layout problem?

**I don't want to use floats, probably not inline-block, nor JS based solution like Packery/Masonry**

Please use modern CSS in your answers because I already know how to solve this with plain old CSS / JS. I target modern browsers only (to be defined)

---

## Solution

Here is my [final result](http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/21/), for those interested to reuse this layout.

Also a very nice visual Flexbox tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Comment: Regarding the vertical spaces, seems fine to me.

Comment: have you looked into the new bootstrap 4, its a beta version but it might be useful

Comment: @Ionut the question is not about weither it looks fine or not, it is how to control it. For example If I want to space the rows vertically of only 1px, I don't know how to do this!

Comment: thanks @jsg I'll take a look for inspiration maybe there will be an elegant and modern solution there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have done this layout using flexbox but it feels quite hacky as I have to compute some margins with maths.

Yes, I think you are using more code than necessary, and not taking advantage of several flexbox features. Your desired layout can be achieved simply and efficiently with flex properties.

**HTML** (removed unnecessary outer container in codepen)

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>j</li>
    <li>k</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** (I compiled your CSS for people who don't use preprocessors)

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    align-content: flex-start; /* solves vertical margin problem (see note below) */
}

li {
    flex: 0 1 200px; /* don't grow, shrink proportionally, start at 200px width */
    background: pink;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px; /* for demo only: center text vertically */
    text-align: center; /* for demo only: center text horizontally */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/

NOTE: In the original code, the space between rows was contracting or expanding relative to the viewport height because when a flexbox is created, a default rule is [`align-content: stretch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-content-property). This means that the layout will expand to fill the size of the container. In the modified code, I override the default with `align-content: flex-start`, which packs the rows at the start of the container.

You were trying to meet several requirements for your grid. I think the modified code covers them all:

- *I'd like to have a grid layout.*
- *... the items have fixed height.*
- *It should be responsive.*
- *The number of colums should be set according to the viewport size.*
- *The DOM should be a simple list of childs inside a container.*
- *I don't want a wrapper element for each row.*
- *The ordering of items matter, so the "b" item of the DOM should be on the right of the "a" item.*

Comment: thanks a lot @Michael_B . This is not exactly what I was looking for but gave me the inspiration to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/2/

Comment: by chance do you know how to do the same thing with non-fixed height items?

Comment: also do you know how to make so that my boxes keep the same width/height ratio? I've tried this but it does not exactly work... http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/7/

Comment: re: same width/height ratio: For your particular code, I would say pick *one* value for `flex-basis`, and use it in all your media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/10/

Comment: I know you're using media queries, but there's another way to maintain the aspect ratio without any media queries: [**viewport percentage units**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32174347/3597276). demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/9/

Comment: see also: [How to maintain the aspect ratio of a div using only CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/3597276)

Comment: thanks, I have been able to get my final result :) http://jsfiddle.net/mk8uksb2/21/