# Centering images WITHIN other images, and preserving responsiveness

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm a newbie, and I've quickly gotten in over my head:

I'm trying to create a pattern I can re-use throughout my site:
**two photos, side by side, each with watercolor splashes peeking out from behind them**.

They should scale appropriately down to the smallest screens (I'm pretty agnostic about whether they wrap or not on tiny screens).

Here's my code:

```css
.two-pics {
  width: 100%;
}

.wc-pic-blue {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c4007c65e4c37e086e54/1464452096489/_watercolor-splash-blue.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  padding: 4%;
}

.wc-pic-pink {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c4077c65e4c37e086e6d/1464452103387/_watercolor-splash-magenta.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: right;
  padding: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-pics">
  <div class="wc-pic-blue pic">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c529b09f953f29724252/1464452394022/8248798.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="wc-pic-pink pic">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749ca6e37013bafc39f394d/1464453743501/parade-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

My instinct was to wrap two Divs (identical but for their source images) with background images (the watercolor splashes) inside a parent Div, then stick images within each of the child Divs — and I tried to center the images (both vertically and horizontally) within each of the child Divs, so the watercolor splashes would be equally visible on all sides;

[image: In other words, like this picture.]

By some miracle this actually worked — mostly — but I was finding weird phantom space when I inspected the page; the inner images were never quite centering correctly within their watercolor Divs.

There's also weird stuff happening upon scaling :(

I'm desperately confused — should I be using Flexbox? Nested Divs with background-images?

[Here's my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elybella/qwod5w14/) if anyone is feeling brave and generous :)

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: The best way (semantically, and probably programmatically) would be to set the splash as a background-image, and the image as an actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with the following features:

- flex layout
- viewport percentage units for sizing the images
- absolute positioning to center one image over the other
- media query for vertical alignment on smaller screens

```css
.two-pics {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;        /* 1 */
}
.pic {
  position: relative;
}
img:first-child {
  height: 30vw;                         /* 2 */
}
img:last-child {
  height: 25vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     /* 3 */
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .two-pics {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="two-pics">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c4007c65e4c37e086e54/1464452096489/_watercolor-s.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c529b09f953f29724252/1464452394022/8248798.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c4077c65e4c37e086e6d/1464452103387/_watercolor-splash-magenta.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749ca6e37013bafc39f394d/1464453743501/parade-2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174347/3597276
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817384/3597276

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qwod5w14/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant! I also think I can learn something by examining this code :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I centered the images on the screen by aligning the left div right and solved the scaling problem. I also added a `@media` query for smaller screens, it looks very fine.

[Improved Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwod5w14/6/)

```css
.two-pics {
    width: 100%;
}

.wc-pic-blue {
    width: 49%; /* decrease for more space between images */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c4007c65e4c37e086e54/1464452096489/_watercolor-splash-blue.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    float: left;
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: right;
}

.wc-pic-pink {
    width: 49%; /* decrease for more space between images */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c4077c65e4c37e086e6d/1464452103387/_watercolor-splash-magenta.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    padding: 4%;
}

.two-pics .pic img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .two-pics .pic {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8%;
    }
    .two-pics .pic img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="two-pics">
    <div class="wc-pic-blue pic">
        <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749c529b09f953f29724252/1464452394022/8248798.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="wc-pic-pink pic">
        <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/57476d871bbee069994f419a/t/5749ca6e37013bafc39f394d/1464453743501/parade-2.jpg">
    </div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Aloso — this also seems to achieve exactly what I'm trying to do. Much appreciated!