# (Flex) - Adobe AIR - font-size with em? With percentage?

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to resize my Adobe AIR app fonts according to screen size with CSS. It seems that `em` is not a valid CSS value, and also `%`.

```
font-size:8%;   // Not a valid value
font-size:8em;  // Not a valid value
```

What CSS values can I use to set a dynamic `font-size` (using AIR 24)?

Please note that I **do not** want to use `@media` CSS queries.

Comment: The only screen size value is `vw` or `vh`...`em` are proportional to the parent's font-size,

Comment: Have you tried *vh* / *vw* units? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32174298/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B The problem is that AIR does not support these values.

Comment: @Paulie_D The problem is that AIR does not support these values.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you ware out of luck...and need a javascript(?) solution to change the font-size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flash/AIR, CSS is parse a little bit different and only numbers are useable:

> *fontSize* - Only the numeric part of the value is used. Units (px, pt) are not parsed; pixels and points are equivalent.

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.

Flash/AIR also has different CSS media queries. If you end up going this route you would probably want to use something like the `application-dpi`:

```
@media (application-dpi: 160) { 
    .someStyle {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

@media (application-dpi: 240) { 
    .someStyle {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff2.html#WS19f279b149e7481c4a89460c12d804a111e-8000

You probably could also try modifying the styles through code:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
if(someScreenSizeVariable < 640) {
    tf.size = 10;
} else {
    tf.size = 13;
}
StyleManager.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f5b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f3b